# How to overcome 'cold war' in a team?

Tags: team, productivity, leadership

I am a software developer with 3 years of experience. I recently joined a new company as a "Software Engineer". They put me on an offshore team with 4 other developers. We don't have a Lead dev/Team lead, and report individually to the client. My management hardly knows what we do. Now, we have client calls almost every day, and people on my team are trying to act over smart and willing to become a lead of my team.

Two guys are indirectly competing for the post. One of them is a good and dedicated employee and other one has been with this company for 3 years. They argue often, and they don't listen to each other. I think it's spoiling the productivity. Management should assign someone as a lead so this war ends right now.

I have a good reputation in this company, but since I handle training programs and other activities, I can't make suggestions to management about this issue. I am not part of this war to becoming a lead but irritated by all of this.

How can I invite management to take action?

Comment: This post is part rant, part extremely broad question. "What should I do to be myself?" and "not piss any one off" are things we can hardly answer since we don't know you or your colleagues. Can you turn this into a more objective, focussed question?

Comment: You seem to have removed the question altogether in favor of more subjective detail. Did you accidentally remove something you meant to add?

Comment: I have added an actual question. Feel free to change.

Comment: thanks Jan, i want to know how to come out of this politics. instead of managing myself with it. so i removed parts that includes my reactions \

Comment: The client will end up solving this problem for you. Whoever gets things done will be contacted directly from now on.

Comment: @jeffo Unlikely.  Generally there is a no poach agreement as part of any supplier contract.  Were they to attempt to do that it would be very expensive.  They are more likely to find a new supplier though

Comment: Chad: Management has no idea whats going on since formally everything is good but internal communication and team collaboration are the problems. I just joined in this company and not in this mess, one guy works in this company since its started but corrupt, One innocent and experienced dev with no team leading skills.

Comment: I spoke to my team yesterday. points i got are, 1.Tasks are delayed because of miscommunication. 2.Productivity loss due to work items are not stream lined with estimation, 3. Egoistic behaviour like "Why should i do what my colleague says ? i ll talk to client regarding my work item." so, I decided to talk to management about this issue since this is a good client. I would suggest to provide a lead developer who gets requirements from client and assign to all of us. or make one of us responsible for such task and introduce estimation docs for work items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try and talk to your team first, explain that you feel its spoiling the productivity. People tend to get annoyed if you just go above their heads and straight to management. You do not want to risk your own position within the team and have them all gang up on you rather than squabble, trust me its not nice.

Sit them down and talk, be assertive, tell them.

If this does not resolve the situation, THEN consider going to management. Email him and tell him you had a meeting/didn't have a meeting and raise your concerns.

Thats what I would do

Comment: With regards to [this excellent meta post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2338/10912) would you mind expanding the 'why' parts of your answer a bit?

Comment: As in why I would do it, it does say ill expand a little though.

Comment: As in why is it a good idea or why does it solve to the problem.

Comment: Thought I had covered the good idea part when i said do not risk your own position, will look into it.

Comment: This is what i gotta do.

Answer (score 6):

Resolving this is the management's job. You say "I can't suggest management about this issue". Why not? You should not take sides, but you can request management to take action. That action is not necessarily appointing a lead - leave it to managment how to resolve this. (You could even argue that only appointing a lead will not solve the conflict).

If you have an HR contact, use that.

Stress that you have a concern about [productivity, loss of enthusiasm](http://www.conflictatwork.com/conflict/cost_e.cfm) in the team, etc.
Make sure you support your request with facts. How much time gets wasted, where does the client suffer (e.g. contradictory communication). Make a list of these things happening. [Try to keep blame out of the list](http://www.margaretwheatley.com/articles/solvingnotattacking.html), just focus on the productivity loss.

Edited:
After reading the other answer from Marriott81 I agree you should try that first. But here too, collect your data.

Comment: With regards to [this excellent meta post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2338/10912) would you mind expanding the 'why' parts of your answer a bit?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Don't get involved - leave it to the competitors and management to resolve. It may be a short term issue and, once decided, will ease the negative atmosphere in the office.
2. Go directly to the management team and tell someone in a position of responsibility what is happening. Keep it brief and to the point. Hopefully the people at that level will be smart enough not to name you when dealing with the situation.

With either option don't take sides with either competitor, just focus on the tasks assigned to you and complete them to the best of your ability. Aligning yourself with either competitor will have implications for you once the decision has been made: you need to focus on the scope of your role and ensure you're doing everything possible to meet the demands set out for you.

To be honest, if the two people competing for the same role are creating that atmosphere neither are suitable for leadership at this stage and are unlikely to be able to settle things directly if you approach them about it.

(edited with explanation of reasoning as suggested by a comment)

Comment: Hi Rex, welcome to [workplace.se]. While your answer may be spot-on, may I suggest, you extend it a little, also explaining why there are only these two options, or what makes them stand out in particular?

Comment: Sure - sorry for not going to into depth. Happy to extend further if requested

Comment: If you choose option #2, don't lay blame, and don't tell management what to do.  Simply lay out the issue and the problem it creates, and tell them you're willing to help in any way management requires.  Leave it at that.  Don't bring it up again.  Management may/will come to you when they feel they need you again.  Also - expect *EVERYTHING* you say to eventually make its way to the two parties involved, so be objective and non-judgmental.

Comment: Agree 100% with @WesleyLong